# If $G$ is a simple $(p,q)$ graph which has two pendant vertices then the complement of G also has at most two pendant vertices

Tags: graph-theory

So we were asked to prove this statement. I did come up with a proof but I am doubtful if my proof is correct.

**Definitions:**

1. A $(p,q)$ graph is a graph with $p$ vertices and $q$ edges,
2. Degree of a vertex is the number of vertices adjacent to that vertex
3. A pendant vertex is a vertex of degree 1
4. The complement of a graph $G$, which we shall denote by $G^c$, is a graph on the same vertices as $G$ such that two distinct vertices of $G^c$ are adjacent if and only if they are not adjacent in $G$

**My Attempt:** Case 1) Suppose $p=3$. Now since we have two pendant vertices in $G$, say $u$ and $v$. They should be adjacent to either third vertex or adjacent to each other. If they are adjacent to third vertex,  $G^c$ will have $u$ and $v$ adjacent to each other. If they are adjacent to each other in $G$, then in $G^c$ they are adjacent to the third vertex. In either case, Both $G$ and $G^c$ have exactly two pendant vertices. Thus the result holds true.

Case 2) Suppose $p \neq 3$. Then Since $G$ has 2 pendant vertices, say $v_1$ and $v_2$, both these vertices will have degree $p-2$ in $G^c$ which is $\neq 1$ for arbitrary $p$. Thus we conclude that $v_1$ and $v_2$ cannot be pendant vertices in $G^c$

Let $v_1'$ and $v_2'$ be vertices adjacent to $v_1$ and $v_2$ respectively. Either $v_1$ and $v_2$ can be adjacent to same vertex (then $v_1' = v_2'$) or they are adjacent to different vertices. In either case, $G$ has at most two vertices which are adjacent to pendant vertices.

Consider a vertex in G which is neither a pendant vertex nor its adjacent vertex. This vertex is not adjacent to both $v_1$ as well as $v_2$. Thus, it will be adjacent to both $v_1$ and $v_2$ in $G^c$. Thus such a vertex will have degree $\geq 2$ in $G^c$. Thus such a vertex cannot be pendant vertex in $G^c$.

Thus, the only possible pendant vertices in $G^c$ are those adjacent to pendant vertices in $G$, which are at most two in number.

Hence the proof

Does this proof make sense?

Comment: Say $v,w$ have degree $1$ in $G$ and $x,y,z$ have degree $1$ in $G^c$. Consider the subgraph $H$ induced by those $5$ vertices. If a simple graph on $5$ vertices has $2$ vertices of degree $1$, then it has at most $5$ edges. If a simple graph on $5$ vertices has $3$ vertices of degree $1$, then it has at most $4$ edges. So $H$ and $H^c$ hace at most $9$ edges between them, which is impossible, since they must have $\binom52=10$ edges between them.

Comment: And thank you for your proof as well.